# How to span a view across all columns?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In a TableLayout, is it possible to make a view span across all columns?

Setting layout_span to a large number (eg. 42) as in colspan in HTML doesn't seem to work.
I also tried making the view the only view in the row and setting the layout_weight property to 1 and it still doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally found a solution.
Setting the stretchColumns attribute of the TableLayout element to "*" did the trick. If you have more than one columns, you also need to set the layout_span property of the view to more than or equal to the maximum number of columns across all the rows.